# Configure Default Memory Requests and Limits for specific pods

Tags: kubernetes

I have a use case where I want to apply different default memory and CPU for containers running with low priority class attached. I have followed the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-default-namespace/) but it applies on namespace level and hence on all the containers in namespace, I want it to make it conditional if container is having priority class then different limitrange object should get applied?

I have tried

```
limitRangeList:
  - name: image-builder
    spec:
      limits:
        - default:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 1Gi
          defaultRequest:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 1Gi
          type: Container
      scopeSelector:
        matchExpressions:
          - operator: In
            scopeName: PriorityClass
            values: ["imagebuild-priority"]

  - name: default
    spec:
      limits:
      - default:
          cpu: {{ limitrange_default_limits_cpu }}
          memory: {{ limitrange_default_limits_memory }}
        defaultRequest:
          cpu: {{ limitrange_default_requests_cpu }}
          memory: {{ limitrange_default_requests_memory }}
        type: Container
```

Comment: What kind of resource is your YAML file?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the API reference ([limitrangeitem](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#limitrangeitem-v1-core), [limitrangespec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#limitrangespec-v1-core)), it looks like you can't apply a limit range to a subset of Pods in a namespace.

I would recommend you look at [admission webhooks](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/extensible-admission-controllers/) instead. As specified in the documentation:

> Mutating admission Webhooks [...] can modify objects
>   sent to the API server to enforce custom defaults.

What you can do is make a mutating admission webhook that intercepts all Pod creations and applies default limits and requests based on the labels specified in the Pod.

Comment: I tried with mutation webhook but somehow it is first going to api server where defaults are getting applied and then it is coming to mutation server with defaults applied. this doesnt work out in case user has explicitly specified then we dont know who has applied the limits

Comment: You need to remove all defaults from the LimitRange first. You then implement the limit and request defaults in the webhook.